# Here maps toll roads in GB

Tags: here-api

I'm using here maps in my application to calculate toll roads. But in GB it works differently. See picture below:

[[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCfR6.png]]

As you can see, there are fields like **name** and **tollSystemId** for others than GB and only **adminId** for GB. Can you explain the reason for this? Or how should I work with GB tolls?

Here is a query sample:
https://tce.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?alternatives=0&commercial=1&cost_optimize=0&currency=EUR&detail=1&driver_cost=0&emissionType=5&height=4&length=16.6&limitedWeight=25&linkattributes=sh%2Cle&maneuverattributes=po%2Cli%2Cno%2Crs&metricsystem=metric&mode=fastest%3Btruck%3Btraffic%3Adisabled&rollup=tollsys%2Ccountry%2Cnone&routeattributes=wp%2Cno%2Csh%2Csm%2Csc&shippedHazardousGoods=&tollVehicleType=3&trailerHeight=4&trailerNumberAxles=3&trailerType=2&trailersCount=1&truckRestrictionPenalty=soft&vehicleNumberAxles=2&vehicleWeight=24&vehicle_cost=0&waypoint0=48.85661400000001%2C2.3522219000000177&waypoint1=51.48158100000001%2C-3.1790899999999738&weightPerAxle=10.5&width=2.45

Comment: Hi, can you please share the exact queries you are are making to our endpoints to help reproduce the issue. Thanks

Comment: Hello @HEREDeveloperSupport, thank you for the reply. I've updated my question with the query sample.

Answer (score 0):

For a toll amount, these properties are possible:

```
"CurrencyAmount": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "adminId": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "country's admin place id"
        },
        "amountInTargetCurrency": {
          "type": "number",
          "format": "double"
        },
        "country": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "languageCode": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "Language code of toll system name"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "Toll system name"
        },
        "tollSystemId": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
```

So for your query in GB, only the `adminId` and `amountInTargetCurrency` are available in our database. So for your usage, you can check if a property key is available in the response before trying to use its value.

So with respect to your query, the truck, goes through three toll roads (1 in France and 2 in Great Britain). The details of each toll road is returned in the response. For France the details are:

```
            {
              "tollSystemId": "5171",
              "name": "SANEF",
              "languageCode": "ENG",
              "amountInTargetCurrency": 65.3
            }
```

and for Great Britain, this information is returned for the two toll roads:

```
    {
      "adminId": "20248595",
      "amountInTargetCurrency": 2.25
    },
    {
      "adminId": "20287683",
      "amountInTargetCurrency": 2.25
    }
```

You can see for each toll road, the amount is available in the response. **So we have toll information in Great Britain.** If you look further in the response you see the total toll cost is `69.8` which is the sum of the toll in France and the tolls in GB.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Does this mean that you don't have information about toll roads in GB? Or GB has a different approach to calculate this?